# Как pandas рассчитывает sem()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Для начала импортируем pandas и создадим Series с идеальным нормальным распределением:

```
import pandas as pd

lst = [[5 for x in range(5)], [4 for x in range(4)], [3 for x in range(3)],
       [2 for x in range(2)], [1 for x in range(1)], [2 for x in range(2)],
       [3 for x in range(3)], [4 for x in range(4)], [5 for x in range(5)]]

lst = [item for sublists in lst for item in sublists]

series = pd.Series(lst)
```

Проверим, что мы создали данные с нормальным распределением:

```
print(round(sum(series - series.mean()) / series.count(), 1) == 0)
#если распределение нормальное, будет выведен ноль
```

А теперь выводим sem() для ГС (генеральной совокупности):

```
print(series.sem(ddof=0))
# 0.21619987017
```

А теперь для выборки:

```
print(series.sem()) #ddof=1
# 0.220026713637
```

Но я не пойму как pandas рассчитывает стандартную ошибку среднего. Делает ли он выборки, если это ГС? И если да, то сколько и можно ли/как указать количество?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Pandas делает это следующим образом](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/nanops.py#L420):

```
def nansem(values, axis=None, skipna=True, ddof=1):
    var = nanvar(values, axis, skipna, ddof=ddof)

    mask = isnull(values)
    if not is_float_dtype(values.dtype):
        values = values.astype('f8')
    count, _ = _get_counts_nanvar(mask, axis, ddof, values.dtype)
    var = nanvar(values, axis, skipna, ddof=ddof)

    return np.sqrt(var) / np.sqrt(count)
```

Определения вызываемых функций можно посмотреть в файле по ссылке

[scipy.stats](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html) предлагает гораздо больше возможностей и он прекрасно работает с Pandas структурами - пример:

```
In [83]: from scipy.stats import *

In [84]: sem(series)
Out[84]: 0.22002671363672216

In [85]: series.sem()
Out[85]: 0.22002671363672216
```

> за что у него отвечает атрибут axis

проще всего показать на примере Pandas.DataFrame:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5,3)), columns=list('abc'))

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
   a  b  c
0  0  1  7
1  8  1  1
2  8  2  7
3  1  3  8
4  1  0  4

In [3]: df.sum(axis=0)
Out[3]:
a    18
b     7
c    27
dtype: int64

In [4]: df.sum(axis=1)
Out[4]:
0     8
1    10
2    17
3    12
4     5
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! А за что у него отвечает атрибут axis? Очень часто встречается

Comment: Я полагаю, что это задание оси, как надо проходиться: вертикально или горизонтально, но я никак не могу найти документацию к тому, что объяснило бы что это, какие значения допустимы, а метод тыка вызывает исключения

Comment: да, именно так. В случае одномерных массивов/векторов - это не важно

Comment: А как поступать в случае матриц?

Comment: @KitScribe, я привел небольшой пример в ответе - на функции суммы нагляднее получается

Comment: всё, спасибо, большое, понял! 1 - по горизонтали, 0 - по вертикали. Ещё есть какие-то варианты?